# MongoDB - embedding, inserting one collection into another

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection (named e.g. people) that looks like

```
{
   _id: ObjectID("5e12f6260c190f8ee91b162d"),
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   address: "Highway To Hell 21"
 }
```

and I want to remove this value for address, and embed the collection (addresses) into it:

```
               {
                  _id: ObjectID("5e25fg3gjh48ee91b2653"),
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
```

to look like:

```
{
   _id: ObjectID("5e12f6260c190f8ee91b162d"),
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   address: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

How would I do this?

Would it be something similar to inserting the new column, like in the code below (or something completely different)?

```
 var bulkInsert = db.people.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
 db.addresses.find().forEach(
    function(doc){
      bulkInsert.insert(doc);
    }
  )
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please share schema ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [$lookup with empty](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) `pipeline` to embed one (entire collection) into another.

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "addresses",
            pipeline: [ ],
            as: "addresses"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CnYqmJuFQRa)

Then you can either use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) (replace the output collection entirely with aggregation result) or [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) (incorporates aggregation results into existing collection):

EDIT:

You can add `$match` to target single document instead of entire collection:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "addresses",
            pipeline: [ { $match: { street: "123 Fake Street" } } ],
            as: "addresses"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the great and quick response. How can I, similarly to this, insert one specific document for all values in a column - actually, how can I target a specific document in another collection with lookup (by _id field)?

Comment: @Mata modified my answer

Comment: And when I use out (or merge), if I want to update multiple documents this way, when I write and run a script, only the last document fetched to the script is updated. How can I overcome this?

Comment: It should replace existing collection - make sure that you preserve `_id` values in your last aggregation step

Comment: So if I put db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "addresses",
            pipeline: [ { $match: { street: "123 Fake Street" } } ],
            as: "address"
        }
    },
  {
    $out: "embeded_set"
  }
]) , and then after that this: db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "addresses",
            pipeline: [ { $match: { street: "Next street" } } ],
            as: "address2"
        }
    },
  {
    $out: "embeded_set"
  }
]) , only the last variable in the lookup (address2) is updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mata `$out` has to be the last pipeline statement since it entirely replaces existing collection. Use `$merge` instead.

Comment: I tried putting merge and I get the same thing - I tried to put merge on every aggregation, and also I tried putting out in the first aggregation and merge on all others, and I still get the same result, i.e. only the last document gets updated.